# How to clone scroll move of textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to duplicate a textarea behaviour on div. 
Especially scroll position. To accomplish it I created angular directive to bind keyup and scroll events on textarea. If one of them trigger I update the div's scrollTop with textarea's scrollTop.

It works expected with one issue. When I type multiple newlines till scroll shown on textarea, scroll position of div not updated till first type.

I check that both has different scrollHeight value at this time. I believe it's the issue.

Here is the jsfiddle to demonstrate issue;

https://jsfiddle.net/4thxsx6w/8/

```
myApp.directive("scrollBottom", function () {
return {
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {

        var id = $("#" + attr.scrollBottom);
        $(element).on("scroll", function () {
            id.scrollTop(this.scrollTop);
            console.log("scroll:" + this.scrollTop);
        });

        $(element).on("keyup", function () {
            console.log("keyup:" + this.scrollTop);
            id.scrollTop(this.scrollTop);
        });

    }
}});
```

Comment: Aparently when you enter a new line, the div doesnt consider the line height of the last line until you put some content there.

Comment: yes it looks like it's the reason, any suggestion to overcome issue?

Comment: Sneak some invisible content in, take your measurement, then take it out?